# Unable to open 1 bit binary image in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, image, opencv, binary, imread

If I check for empty image it returns true while reading binary image using imread

```
original_img = imread("E:/Newfolder/ER41615-12.TIF",  CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYCOLOR );
```

Comment: there are no '1 bit' images in opencv. try CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE

Comment: I want to load a binary image using OpenCV. The bit depth of image is 1 bit

Answer (score 0):

From the [doc](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imread)

> The function imread loads an image from the specified file and returns
>   it.
>        If the image cannot be read (because of missing file, improper permissions,
>        unsupported or invalid format), the function returns
>        an empty matrix ( Mat::data==NULL ).

and Mat::empty() will return true.

Comment: The image path is correct, the reason i have found so far is that the TIFF uses tags and the image i am using does not contain one

Comment: @HimanshuVerma well, then we goes into "unsupported or invalid format" case. If libtiff shipped with OpenCV can read this file you can always submit bug against OpenCV :)